# browserify transform options are disappearing

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am working on a browserify transform and I am passing in options.

```
//excerpt from package.json of my application that is using my transform and extension
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    ["mytransform", {"extensions": ["my-extension"] } ]
  ]
}
```

The transform is working and is called on the first file and then on files depended on by that file.  The problem I am having is that I am losing the options.

In my transform I have

```
module.exports = function (file, options) {
  console.log('processing? ', file, options);
  options = options || {};
  options.extensions = options.extensions || [];
  var extensions = options.extensions.map(function(extensionId){
                                            return require(extensionId)();
                                          }),
      data = '';

  var stream = through(write, end);
  return stream;

  function write(buf) { data += buf; }
  function end() {
    var out = processFile(extensions, file, data);
    stream.queue(out || data);
    stream.queue(null);
  }
};
```

The following is the output.  The options are there for the first file, but then nothing in the second file

```
processing?  /path/to/cascadingAmdDepWithPlugin.js { extensions: [ 'my-extension' ]}
processing?  /path/to/node_modules/dojo/number.js { }
```

How do I get my options to carry through to all files being handled by my transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are working as expected.  I didn't carefully read the documentation carefully enough.  Transforms aren't applied to files within `node_modules`.  Solutions are to either specify the transform as global or update `package.json` of the project within `node_modules`.  Once I did either of those things, my code worked as expected.

Comment: How did u specified the transform with options as global?

Comment: Browserify transforms only run on modules that have a transform specifed in their `package.json`.  So if project `a` depends on project `b`, but only project `a` specifies a browserify transform, then only the transform will run on project `a`.  Browserify will run on both projects, but only apply the transform to one.  You can either update the `package.json` of project `b` or you need to specify that a transform is global.  The [docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#btransformtr-opts) say this is done via `global` parameter you pass to the transform options.